# How can I animate all tab icons (not just one) when pressed?

Tags: ios, xcode, swiftui

I'm using an if statement but it only works on the notification bell icon, How can I apply the same effect to the other icons? Should I use a switch statement?

```
  if selection == index {
                        Color(.label)
                            .frame(height: 2)
                            .offset(y: -8)
                            .matchedGeometryEffect(id: "currentTab", in: currentTab)
                    }
                    if tabs[selection].label == "Notifications" && tabs[index].label  == "Notifications" {
                        Image(systemName: tabs[index].image)
                            .frame(height: 20)
                            .rotationEffect(.degrees(25))
                        
                    }   else {
                        Image(systemName: tabs[index].image)
                            .frame(height: 20)
                            .rotationEffect(.degrees(0))
                        
                    }
                    
                    
                    Text(tabs[index].label) .font(.caption2)
                        .fixedSize()
                        .foregroundColor(.blue)
              }
                .fixedSize(horizontal: false, vertical: true)
                .frame(width: geometry.size.width / 2, height: 44, alignment: .bottom).padding(.horizontal).foregroundColor(selection == index ? Color(.label) : .secondary )
                .onTapGesture{
                    withAnimation{selection = index}
                }
            }
        
        }
    }.frame(height: 44, alignment: .bottom)
}
```

}

[image]

Comment: I'm not really clear on what the question is here. Can you include a [mre]?

Comment: @jnpdx Thank you for bringing this to my attention, kindly let me know if this suffices.

Comment: A [mre] should be copy and pastable into Xcode and demonstrate the scenario.